# Custom Twitter Popup

Tags: twitter

I want to implement Twitter share button, and after you share to get suggestion to follow an user.
I have implemented like this:

```
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
                                       data-dnt="true"
                                       data-count="none"
                                       data-via="twitter_user"
                                       data-size="large">
                                        Tweet
  </a>
```

So, I click on Twitter button, one pop-up is opened with share, after that in the same pop-up I get a suggestion to follow "twitter_user".
How can I make stylization on Twitter button and some stylization inside pop-up? It is possible?
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img912/3984/TQC0Ew.png this is the pop-up with suggestion to follow and I want to remove "Get a Tweet button for your own website" (for example).

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can freely choose the way you style an intent to post on Twitter by using [Twitter Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents). It's just a way to build a link URL in a way that will open the tweet composer just like the Tweet Button.

Example: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=32579487338074112&related=SteveMartinToGo,twitterapi

It's not possible to do customization on the screen after the tweet is posted.